# Visual Studio 2015 + Windows Dark Theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10, when I change the theme to Hight Contrast (Dark) in the OS display settings my Visual Studio 2015 shows all code monocromatically as follows:

[image]
Visual Studio doesn't allows me to change the "Color theme" in the menu Options > Environment > General.

I've tried to delete all my Visual Studio's user settings but the problem persists. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: "Anybody else having this issue?" is not a good SO question.  Recommend you rephrase to "how do I fix the problem?"

Comment: Ok, changed. Thanks.

Comment: Have you given this [SO answer a try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31537057/4270650)?

Comment: I've checked now and It worked. I've made a little adjustment, applying the solution on folder  "14.0_Config" instead of "11.0_Config". Thank you.