# VS2017 Color Theme disabled under Windows High Contrast Theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

OS: Win7

[Regedit trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400575/1152243) doesn't work as the VS Config key is gone.

PS, The high contrast theme is said to be helpful for ophthalmic health, avoiding glares to eyes.

Comment: It is still there, just harder to get to.  Google "vs2017 config registry key" for hits, takes [you here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41122603/17034).

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! Could you answer this please? Btw, Powershell script is also good, except need to find/replace name and VS Version.