# How do I use SQL Management Studio 2017 with Dark Theme with Windows 10 High Contrast theme?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, windows-10, themes, high-contrast

I've followed this guide to enable dark theme in VS2017 with the high contrast Windows theme: [How do I use visual studio 2012 dark theme with windows 8 high contrast theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305176/how-do-i-use-visual-studio-2012-dark-theme-with-windows-8-high-contrast-theme][1])

Works great.

Now I'm trying with SQL Mangement Studio 2017.

I have enabled the Dark Theme in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef

But it looks like it's being overruled by the High Contrast theme from Windows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBGE2.png

I've been digging around in RegEdit and found the themes of Sql Studio in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0_Config\Themes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/51MhW.png

There are 4 themes.

a5c004b4-2d4b-494e-bf01-45fc492522c7 is the High Contrast theme, and its is locked

I've tried the following without luck:

- Delete a5c004b4-2d4b-494e-bf01-45fc492522c7 -> it just gets created again when sql mangement studio starts
- Replace its the contents of a5c004b4-2d4b-494e-bf01-45fc492522c7 with the dark theme: 1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749 -> it just gets overwritten once the program starts
- Disable it just like the Dark Theme was in ssms.pkgundef -> sql studio cannot start

It looks like the theme is being inject on program start, so maybe there's a way to disable that?

any suggestions :P?

Answer (score 5):

You can import custom fonts and color settings in SSMS. Just follow this guide:

https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a nice dark theme back to SSMS 2016 while Windows 10 is set to High Contrast by simply downloading and importing the theme (vssettings) from here: https://mikesdatawork.wordpress.com/2017/07/07/dark-ssms-theme-ssms-2017/ 
This link also included detailed instructions on how to do this. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the ShellColors.pkgdef, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.pkgdef, and EditorColors.pkgdef files in the "\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform" folder of the ssms installation folder.  You can copy the settings for the dark theme over to the high contrast settings.  These files will most likely get overridden every time you update ssms, so be aware that you will need to do this every time you update or will need a script to update the files.